# Eclipse crashed on Debug

Tags: eclipse

I have a problem with my Eclipse. I'm running in Debug mode and I add a breakpoint in the code, but when I get to the breakpoint it seems that the eclipse crashes, it doesn't do anything else and the debug keys don't even work (F7,F8). And when I try to evaluate any variable I get an error. Does anyone know how to solve?

[image]

Comment: Do you mean it literally crashes to the desktop, or is it only unable to evaluate what you've selected?

Comment: it locks the breakpoint and doesn't let it continue

Comment: Even Step Over?